# understanding interleaving of noise and i.i.d. noise in communication problem

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, information-theory, ergodic-theory

I'm trying to figure out the role of interleaving in communication. All I found in the Internet are some high-level interpretations of it, e.g. spreading out the error to against burst errors. I also found in a paper saying for a channel with additive ergodic noise, one can use interleaving argument and treat the channel as with additive i.i.d. noise.

I'm looking for a more mathematical proof for this 'interleaving produce uncorrelated noise' argument, and I guess this uncorrelated (or i.i.d., I'm not sure) comes from the random selection of the permutation in interleaving. I tried to prove that
$P(U_{\Pi}(i)=u|U_{\Pi}(j)=v)=P(U_{\Pi}(j)=v|U_{\Pi}(i)=u)$, which is the condition for independent random varialbes. Take the random selection of permutation in consideration,
$$\begin{align}
P(U_{\Pi}(i)=u|U_{\Pi}(j)=v)=\sum_{\pi}P(U_{\Pi}(i)=u|U_{\Pi}(j)=v,\Pi=\pi)Pr(\Pi=\pi).
\end{align}$$
I have no clue how to continue.

Comment: start by looking at how correlation (of a stochastic process) is defined. It seems that you are confusing "uncorrelated" with "independent". Two variables (or, in this case, two samples of a stochastic process) may be uncorrelated but not necessarily independent.

Comment: Hi @Stelios I'm in fact confusing whether interleaving leads to uncorrelated noise or i.i.d. noise, since I saw some high-level intepretation saying interleaving decorrelated the noise, while in a paper it said interleaving enables us to treat the ergodic noise as i.i.d. one